# Get list of files inside a running Kubernetes Pod's memory

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

Is it possible to get a list files which are occupying a running Pods memory? I have tried metrics-server but that just tells memory and CPU usage per pod and node. Much appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of the processes in each of pod's containers, or a list of the files in each container?

Comment: List of files in PODs memory.

Comment: The list of file on a pods file system?

Comment: Did you mean, you need to get a list of files in the container(s) running inside the pod?

Comment: In one of my environment CPU and memory utilization is going beyond the limit. And Azure Kubernetes Service is not recreating the POD. So I am thinking to look into more details as to what is occupying pod or containers memory?

Answer (score 6):

By assuming what you looking is to list the files inside the container(s) in the pod, you can simply execute `kubectl exec` command,

List down the pods

```sh
kubectl get pods
```

Get the pod name.

List the filesystem contents,

```sh
kubectl exec -it <pod Name> ls
```

or even,

```sh
kubectl exec -it <pod Name> ls <desired path>
```

Comment: Just a note that this requires the `ls` binary to be available in the container, which isn't always the case.

Comment: Good point @Matt yes I have missed it. Of course there are some skinny images which may not include the ls binaries. What we can do a scenario as such?

Comment: Probably have to use [`nsenter`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) on the container host.

Comment: Or just plain `ls` on the host if you know where the container runtime stores files and they are mounted.